# Order by related table column

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a query like:

```
$users = User::with('role')
    ->get();
```

How can I order the results by the related table, so it's something like:

```
$users = User::with('role')
    ->orderBy('role.id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Is there a way to do it without joining the `role` table (since we're already doing `with('role')`?

Answer (score 1):

what are you trying to order. the list of users or the roles.
if you are trying to sort the users base on role do.

```
$users = User::with('role')->orderBy('role_id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

if you are trying to sort the roles of the user then pocho's answer is correct.

```
$users = User::with(array('role' => function($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC');

}))->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading):

```
$users = User::with(array('role' => function($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC');

}))->get();
```

You can also do a raw query using DB::raw like in the examples [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions).

Comment: I'm not getting the same order if I compare your query against this one: http://pastebin.com/7dt4HPJC

Comment: Becouse @Poncho is ordering roles, not users.

Comment: That's right. It's sorting roles, not users. No need for the downvote @user5140488 just trying to be helpful

Answer (score -1):

You can always sort the returned collection quite easily...

```
$users = User::with('role')
    ->get()
    ->sortBy(function($user, $key)
    {
        return $user->role->id;
    });
```

This is assuming a user hasOne or belongsTo a role.  If your relationship is something that can return multiple roles, then it becomes a bit more complex because you need to decide which of the user's roles to sort by.

Comment: Also assuming that table has no more than few hundred rows. This is very bad for performance.